# Create DNS entry for docker container in Pi-hole

Tags: networking, docker, pi-hole

My dockerized web server is accessible on my LAN with its host name, let's say, `jarvis` (url: `http://jarvis/`).

I have a Gitea instance running in my local network which is accessible via `http://jarvis:3000`. It runs on the same machine as the webserver does and runs inside a Docker container as well with container name, let's say, `gitea`. They share the same docker network so the web server can access the gitea instance through `http://gitea:3000`.

Now, in my Pi-hole, I wanted to create a local DNS entry to access my git repository directly via, let's say, `http://git.home`. However, since Pi-hole DNS entries don't accept entries with ports (e.g., `http://jarvis:3000`), I'm not quite sure on how to continue.

What I've tried so far:

I tried setting the local DNS to the docker network IP, e.g., `git.home` --> `172.22.1.31`.

Unfortunately, even though the server the Pi-hole runs on is able to ping the given IP and Pi-hole is set up to run on network_mode `host`, I'm unable to access `http://git.home/` through any other computer on my LAN.

Does Pi-hole resolve the IP internally (on the server) or does it just replace `http://git.home` with the given IP (`172.22.1.31`) when accessing it through a computer on the LAN?

**How can I achieve to create a DNS entry (i.e. `http://git.home/`) that routes to `http://jarvis:3000`?**

Apparently, even setting up a reverse proxy on my webserver wouldn't work since I would have to route the proxy to `/git` instead of `/` so I wouldn't be able to create a Local DNS entry on Pi-hole because it only accepts IPs.

I hope that somehow makes sense.

Thanks a lot in advance.